# rake db:seed thorwing Can't mass-assign protected attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I am learning ruby on rails. I am creating a model for storing User information and when calling **rake db:seed** then I am getting the following error , any idea what I am missing  ?

```
rake db:seed

require 'digest'
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password 
  attr_accessible :email, :password
  validates :email, :uniqueness => true, 
                                    :length => {:within => 5..50},
                                    :presence => true

  validates :password, :confirmation => true, :length => { :within => 4..20 }, :presence => true, :if => :password_required?

  has_one :profile

  has_many :articles, :order => 'published_at DESC, title ASC',
                      :dependent => :nullify
  has_many :replies, :through => :articles, :source => :comments

  before_save :encrypt_new_password

  def self.authenticate(email, password)
    user = find_by_email(email)
        return user if user && user.authenticated?(password)
  end

  def authenticated?(password)
    self.hashed_password == encrypt(password)
  end


  def encrypt_new_password
    return if password.blank?
      self.hashed_password  = encrypt(password)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  end

  def password_required?
    hashed_password.blank? || password.present?
  end

 def encrypt(string)
   Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(string)
 end 

end




Can't mass-assign protected attributes: password_confrimation
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.3/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:48:in `process_removed_attributes'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.3/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:20:in `debug_protected_attribute_removal'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.3/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:12:in `sanitize'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.3/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security.rb:230:in `sanitize_for_mass_assignment'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:75:in `assign_attributes'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:498:in `initialize'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:44:in `new'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:44:in `create'
C:/Users/huzaifa.gain/My Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/blog/db/seeds.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:23
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to add `password_confirmation` to `attr_accessible`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password 
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation
```

and it should work.

Comment: @Gainster: Make sure to use the correct attribute name and beware of typos.

Comment: I am following Begining Rails 3 , It is not making the fields attr_accessible https://gist.github.com/326271 So I dont understand why i have to make them accessible ??

Comment: Depending on the release you're using, Rails 3.2.3 brought a change which protects all models by default. Read the release notes for more information. http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/3/30/ann-rails-3-2-3-has-been-released/

Comment: Isn't there a way to turn this off so you do not have to re-write all your models, then change them all back after seeding?

Answer (score 0):

As logs says "Can't mass-assign protected attributes: password_confrimation" 
you need to add password_confrimation to User Model

attr_accessible :password_confrimation