# Can't mass-assign protected attributes: password_confrimation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I dont know why I am getting the following error about mass-assignment protected. Though I have cofiguration setting to config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false

Follwoing is the code for model and controller

Any ideas?

```
      ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in UsersController#create 
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: password_confrimation
Rails.root: C:/Users/huzaifa.gain/My Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/blog

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:7:in `new'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:7:in `create'


Request

Parameters: 
{"utf8"=>"?",
 "authenticity_token"=>"CIPrmS9ZZlgUELOMkAT6Htw1eLPMxmXRh7Ur7doeYcY=",
 "user"=>{"email"=>"huzi",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "password_confrimation"=>"[FILTERED]"},
 "commit"=>"Create User"}


class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new 
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
       redirect_to_ articles_path, :notice => 'User successfully added.'
     else 
       render :action =>'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(parms[:id]) 
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(parms[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      redirect_to articles_path, :notice => 'Updated user information successfully'
    else 
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end
end


require 'digest'
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor  :email, :password , :password_confirmation
  attr_accessible :email, :password , :password_confirmation
  validates :email, :uniqueness => true, 
                                    :length => {:within => 5..50},
                                    :presence => true

  validates :password, :confirmation => true, :length => { :within => 4..20 }, :presence => true, :if => :password_required?

  has_one :profile

  has_many :articles, :order => 'published_at DESC, title ASC',
                      :dependent => :nullify
  has_many :replies, :through => :articles, :source => :comments

  before_save :encrypt_new_password

  def self.authenticate(email, password)
    user = find_by_email(email)
        return user if user && user.authenticated?(password)
  end

  def authenticated?(password)
    self.hashed_password == encrypt(password)
  end


  def encrypt_new_password
    return if password.blank?
      self.hashed_password  = encrypt(password)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  end

  def password_required?
    hashed_password.blank? || password.present?
  end

 def encrypt(string)
   Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(string)
 end 


end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [rake db:seed thorwing Can't mass-assign protected attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493640/rake-dbseed-thorwing-cant-mass-assign-protected-attributes)

Comment: @HolgerJust I don't think this is a duplicate, it looks like the OP has a typo in their form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's because of a typo. Your model has `attr_accessible :email, :password , :password_confirmation` but it looks like your form spells it password_confrimation.

Comment: There's a [campaign to clean up Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167342) by removing these typo-related questions, we could really use your help! Would you mind pitching in a little by casting a close vote on this question?

Answer (score 0):

Change your form from:

```
:password_confrimation
```

to:

```
:password_confirmation
```

It's a typo.