# rake aborted! Can't mass-assign protected attributes: authentication_token

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I already found some people fixing this issue modifying the attr_accessible but I think this error might be in the gem rake itself?

```
rake --trace db:seed
```

-- log output begin --

```
** Invoke db:seed (first_time)
** Execute db:seed
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
rake aborted!
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: authentication_token
/Users/devx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activemodel-3.2.8/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:48:in `process_removed_attributes'
/Users/devx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activemodel-3.2.8/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:20:in `debug_protected_attribute_removal'
/Users/devx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activemodel-3.2.8/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:12:in `sanitize'
/Users/devx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activemodel-3.2.8/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security.rb:230:in `sanitize_for_mass_assignment'
/Users/devx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:75:in `assign_attributes'
/Users/devx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:498:in `initialize'
/Users/devx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:44:in `new'
/Users/devx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:44:in `create'
/Users/devx/passbook_rails_example/db/seeds.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/devx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/Users/devx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
/Users/devx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/Users/devx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/Users/devx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:520:in `load_seed'
/Users/devx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:309:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/devx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/devx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/devx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/devx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/devx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/devx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/devx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/devx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/devx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/Users/devx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/devx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/Users/devx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/Users/devx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/devx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/Users/devx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/Users/devx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/devx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/Users/devx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/devx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/devx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
/Users/devx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/Users/devx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
```

-- log output end --

Comment: possible duplicate of [rake db:seed thorwing Can't mass-assign protected attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493640/rake-dbseed-thorwing-cant-mass-assign-protected-attributes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not at all related to rake, as you said it's a `MassAssignment` issue, and that can be fixed modifying the `attr_accessible` of the related model.

What actually happens here is that the `seed` task executed by `rake` tries to create models (I guess `User`), and it seems the hash params given to `User.create` contain an `authentication_token` key, it should looks like the following:

```
User.create name: 'foo', email: 'mail@bar.com', authentication_token: 'qfgsdgf' ...
```

But your `User` model doesn't have `:authentication_token` in its `attr_accessible` list, so that's why it's throwing this error when trying to create the `User`.

If you just want a warning instead of an exception when facing `MassAssignment` issues, you can change the config :

in config/environment/{development,test,production}.rb

```
config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict
```

Comment: thanks! it actually worked. I tried adding :token to the attr_accessible but :authentication_token did it.

Comment: you're welcome, you should eventually read the rails guide about mass assignment if you haven't read it yet http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment

Answer (score 0):

Just add the authentication_token to the attr_accessible
Eg:
The error that I was getting

```
Media1s-Mac-mini:rails_apps media1$ rake clipsfree_import RAILS_ENV=development csvfile=/Users/media1/Desktop/clips/atemp5/demotracks2/import.csv
rake aborted!
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: title
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activemodel-3.2.11/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:48:in `process_removed_attributes'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activemodel-3.2.11/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:20:in `debug_protected_attribute_removal'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activemodel-3.2.11/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:12:in `sanitize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activemodel-3.2.11/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security.rb:230:in `sanitize_for_mass_assignment'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:75:in `assign_attributes'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/base.rb:497:in `initialize'
/Users/media1/Desktop/rails_apps/lib/tasks/clipsfree_import.rake:14:in `new'
/Users/media1/Desktop/rails_apps/lib/tasks/clipsfree_import.rake:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/media1/Desktop/rails_apps/lib/tasks/clipsfree_import.rake:5:in `each'
/Users/media1/Desktop/rails_apps/lib/tasks/clipsfree_import.rake:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => clipsfree_import
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Solution:
Added the attribute title to attr_accessible in the loopsfree.rb in the models folder

class Loopsfree < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :ISRC, **:title,** :artist, :bpm, :file_name, :genre, :id, :sub_genre
end

Hope this helps :) 
Happy coding